# such as adding the <span> + </ span> tag inside the <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

The `<span> + </span>` is added outside of the `<a></a>` tag, how can I make the `<span>` show inside the  tag?

In this way:

```
<a>about us <span>+</span></a>
```

**My code:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.accord ul li:has(ul)').addClass('expand').find('ul').hide();
  $('.accord ul li.expand>a').after('<span> + </span>');

  $('.accord ul').on('click', 'li.collapse span ', function (e) {
   $(this).text(' + ').parent().addClass('expand').removeClass('collapse').find('>ul').slideUp();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  $('.accord ul').on('click', 'li.expand span', function (e) {
   $(this).text(' - ').parent().addClass('collapse').removeClass('expand').find('>ul').slideDown();
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  $('.accord ul').on('click', 'li.collapse li:not(.collapse)', function (e) {
   e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- HTML -->
     <div id="Accord" class="accord">
       <ul>
         <li><a href='#'>about us</a>
           <ul class='sub'>
             <li><a href='#'>Text</a><ul><li><a>Text</a></li></ul></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
     </div>
```

Comment: Use `.append()` instead of `.after()`. **Read the doco.** If you're going to use jQuery, spend a couple of minutes browsing through the [list of DOM manipulation methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/). Or skim through the [full list of selectors and methods](http://api.jquery.com/) to get a sense of which ones might be useful to you.

Comment: @nnnnnn it works. But the content is not expanded by pressing **+**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {
  $('.accord ul li:has(ul)').addClass('expand').find('ul').hide();
  $('.accord ul li.expand>a').append('<span> + </span>');

  $('.accord ul').on('click', 'li.collapse a span ', function (e) {
    $(this).text(' + ').closest('li').addClass('expand').removeClass('collapse').find('>ul').slideUp();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  $('.accord ul').on('click', 'li.expand a span', function (e) {
    $(this).text(' - ').closest('li').addClass('collapse').removeClass('expand').find('>ul').slideDown();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });

  $('.accord ul').on('click', 'li.collapse li:not(.collapse)', function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Accord" class="accord">
 <ul>
   <li><a href='#'>about us</a>
     <ul class='sub'>
       <li><a href='#'>Text</a><ul><li><a>Text</a></li></ul></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

You need to use `append` instead of `after` and for finding the li use `closest('li')` instead of `parent`.

Rather than traversing using `parent` use `closest`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Welcome buddy :)

Comment: just a doubt, friend, if I wanted to add in this way: `<a><span>+</span> about us</a>`

Comment: @Alex - replace the `.append()` and use `.prepend()` to make `<a><span>+</span> about us</a>`

Comment: It will be same, only change will be `prepend` instead of `append`

Answer (score 1):

Try using .append() function instead of .after().

[Append documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp)

Comment: it works. But the content is not expanded by pressing **+**

Comment: You are targeting the parent element with .parent(), but now you have added in an extra nested statement, so you have to target two parents above. e.g. .parent().parent(), or use the function .closest()

Answer (score 0):

In your `jquery` replace the `after` to `append` to make the `span` add inside the `a` tag. And updated your `jquery` to make the content expand too. See below code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
 $('.accord ul li:has(ul)').addClass('expand').find('ul').hide();
 $('.accord ul li.expand>a').append('<span> + </span>');

 $('.accord ul').on('click', 'li.collapse span ', function (e) {
  $(this).text(' + ').parents('li').addClass('expand').removeClass('collapse').find('>ul').slideUp();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 });

 $('.accord ul').on('click', 'li.expand span', function (e) {
  $(this).text(' - ').parents('li').addClass('collapse').removeClass('expand').find('>ul').slideDown();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 });

 $('.accord ul').on('click', 'li.collapse li:not(.collapse)', function (e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Accord" class="accord">
 <ul>
   <li><a href='#'>about us</a>
     <ul class='sub'>
       <li><a href='#'>Text</a><ul><li><a>Text</a></li></ul></li>
     </ul>
   </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @alex - another way, Instead of `.parent()`, use `.parents()` with `s` to call the parent `li`,

Comment: Hello @bellabelle Thanks :) I do not have the necessary score for a +1 :(

Comment: @Alex, Its okay, I just want to share my idea

Comment: just a doubt, if I wanted to add in this way: `<a><span>+</span> about us</a>`

Comment: @Alex - replace the `.append()` and use `.prepend()` to make `<a><span>+</span> about us</a>`